# C-program's function seems to return always true, but I don't see why

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, boolean

(I'm new to Stackoverflow.)

I currently work at a regular expression engine for C, but there are some problems.

The first function is called "contains". If you pass two char arrays to that func, one is the source and the other one is the needle you look for in that text, it'll return true if the text contains the snippet or false if it doesn't (also if the needle array has more elements as the text array).

I compile with gcc:

```
gcc -std=c99 test.c regex.c -o test
```

./test

It always prints "Contains", even if the needle's length is bigger.

a snippet:

```
bool contains(const char source[], const char needle[]){

unsigned int source_length = (int)sizeof(source)/sizeof(source[0]);
unsigned int needle_length = (int)sizeof(needle)/sizeof(needle[0]);

if(source_length < needle_length) return false; // this should return false to the test program but it doesn't. What's wrong?

}
```

I think that I just don't see what's wrong. Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

Nick

Comment: How does that compile?  Not all code paths return a value.

Comment: sizeof does not give you the number of elements in the array. It returns the size of a pointer which is either 4 or 8.

Comment: You want `strlen` for getting the length of a string at runtime, not `sizeof`.

Comment: @Beed This is, in many cases, a valid idiom for getting the number of items in an array. But it only works when the size of the array is known at compile time (which isn't the case here).

Comment: The `(int)` cast is bogus, the code is better without it  (in this case it doesn't matter as `sizeof(source)` never exceeds `INT_MAX` but in other cases it may)

Comment: @EricJ failure to return a value from a function does not cause a compiler error

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Been 15+ years since I did any serious C coding.  I guess I just take some things for granted.  Does it return false / null / 0 (depending on return type) if no explicit return is encountered?

Comment: @EricJ. I am pretty sure flowing off the end of a function is undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: @EricJ no, nothing happens. But it is UB if the calling code tries to access the value returned, if no value was returned.

Comment: @EricJ sometimes compilers will be helpful and try to warn, however this isn't possible in general (it's not an error if that code path is never entered; e.g. imagine a function that checks all cases of Fermat's Last Theorem up to 10^80 and returns false if not found, and fails to return if found)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: C# will not compile a method that fails to either return a value or throw an exception in every code path.

Comment: @EricJ how does it determine if a code path exists or not? (e.g. in my example about FLT)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Eric Lippert discusses the issue in relation to lamdas.  http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one/ http://ericlippert.com/2012/10/10/does-not-compute/

Comment: @AndrewMedico this idiom works for any array (of complete type), even if the size is not known at compile-time. It doesn't work for a pointer which may be pointing to an element of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function declaration

```
bool contains(const char source[], const char needle[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
bool contains(const char *source, const char *needle);
```

So inside the function expressions

```
unsigned int source_length = (int)sizeof(source)/sizeof(source[0]);
unsigned int needle_length = (int)sizeof(needle)/sizeof(needle[0]);
```

are equivalent to

```
unsigned int source_length = (int)sizeof( const char * )/sizeof( const char );
unsigned int needle_length = (int)sizeof( const char * )/sizeof( const char );
```

and the both equal to `sizeof( const char * )` because `sizeof( const char )` is equal to 1.

You have to use standard C function `strlen` that to compare lengths of the strings.

For example

```
bool contains(const char source[], const char needle[])
{
   return ( !( strlen( source ) < strlen( needle ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`T t[]` as a function parameter is the same as `T*`. In your example, `source` and `needle` are both `const char*`, so the size of both is the same. Hence, the test always fails. You could easily have checked this by printing out `sizeof(source)` and `sizeof(needle)`.

If the pointers point to nul terminated strings, you can get their length using `strlen`. Otherwise, you need to pass the lengths s separate function parameters.

As an aside, note that you need to return something in all cases. You are not returning when the test fails.

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing the size of a pointer to a char by the size of a single char. They are both constant lengths, so it always returns true.

Specifically, on the OS's I've worked on,

```
sizeof(source) // size of const char* == size of pointer to char == 4
sizeof(needle) // size of const char* == size of pointer to char == 4
sizeof(source[0]) // size of char == 1 
sizeof(neeedle[0]) // size of char == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays as passed to functions by reference rather than value. That means that the function only sees the pointer to the first element and does not know how much space was originally allocated. You'll have to count the number of elements manually -- by iterating over each element until you get the NULL character.

You can use a helper function such as `strlen`, but if you're adverse to importing an additional library, try the following code:

```
bool contains(const char source[], const char needle[])
{
  unsigned int source_length = 0;
  unsigned int needle_length = 0;
  while(source[source_length++] != '\0');
  while(needle[needle_length++] != '\0');
  return !(source_length < needle_length);
}
```

Note that your solution would have worked if the strings had been allocated inside of `contains()` rather than being passed to the function as arguments.

Comment: Thank you. Nice solution, but I need to pass the strings to the function, because it's gonna be a lib or something like this for another project ;)